# Deploy docker-compose file on ECS with multiple services

Tags: amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy a docker-compose file on ECS, that have several services (for the sake of the example lets say 5 services, i.e app, db, logging, etc) on a cluster that have 5 instances of t2.small, now these services require 500MB each to run, so 5 instances should be fine.
However, I am getting `no container instance met all of its requirements`.
ECS here is trying to deploy all of the 5 services to the same EC2 instances. I tried changing the instance type to t2.large, it worked, but only used 1 instances of the 5.
My question is, can you instruct ECS to distribute the services across the whole cluster? 
PS: I am using the cli version of ECS, here are the commands I used:

```
$ ecs-cli up --size 5 --instance-type t2.small --capability-iam


$ ecs-cli compose --file docker-compose.yml service up
```